# Copy to clipboard with Symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony

input value to reflect the value in javascript input value to reflect the value in javascript input value to reflect the value in javascript input value to reflect the value in javascript

```
<div id="goodContent{{ entity.id}}" onclick="copyToClipboard();" style="display:none;">
                            {{ pdf_yolu }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn btn-default" id="clickCopy">Kopyala</div>


document.getElementById("clickCopy").onclick = function() {
            copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("goodContent{{ entity.id}}"));
        };

        function copyToClipboard(e) {
            var tempItem = document.createElement('input');

            tempItem.setAttribute('type','text');
            tempItem.setAttribute('display','none');

            let content = e;
            if (e instanceof HTMLElement) {
                content = e.innerHTML;
            }

            tempItem.setAttribute('value',content);
            document.body.appendChild(tempItem);

            tempItem.select();
            document.execCommand('Copy');

            tempItem.parentElement.removeChild(tempItem);
        }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! In order to attract good answers, please explain your problem and show us a minimal example of the code that is causing issues. You can [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then read on [how to create a good minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then, come back and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Symfony issue as Symfony does not execute its own code on web browsers, which is where you need "copy to clipboard" functionality to run. (You should remove the Symfony tag from your question.) This is entirely JavaScript.

Consider a library such as [ClipboardJS](https://clipboardjs.com/) to do this. I can confirm it is usable on the front end templates of a Symfony based project.

---

In my case I had a table with many rows needing the 2nd column of each row to be copyable with a button. I wanted the button to appear in the first column. Here's the script I wrote:

*Bare in mind I use other front end libraries too such as sprintf, jQuery, jQuery UI, Bootstrap 4, and FontAwesome. You should be able to adapt this though.*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('table').find('tr.js-copyable').each(function(k, v){

        var $tr = $(v).first();
        if ($tr.length != 1) {
            return;
        }

        var $th = $tr.find('th').first();
        if ($th.length != 1) {
            return;
        }

        var $td = $tr.find('td').first();
        if ($td.length != 1) {
            return;
        }

        var value = $td.text();
        if (typeof value != "string" || (value = value.trim()).length < 1) {
            return;
        }

        var tdTooltip = function(text, icon){

            if (typeof text != "string" || (text = text.trim()).length < 1) {
                return;
            }

            if (typeof icon != "string" || (icon = icon.trim()).length < 1) {
                icon = "";
            }

            $td.tooltip('dispose');

            $td.tooltip({
                html: true,
                title: sprintf("<i class=\"fa %s\"></i><span>%s</span>", icon, text),
                trigger: "manual",
                placement: "left",
            });

            $td.tooltip('show');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $td.tooltip('hide');
            }, 2000);

        };

        var $copyButton = $('<button class="btn btn-info js-copy js-tooltip" title="Copy to clipboard"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>');

        var clipboard = new ClipboardJS($copyButton[0], {
            text: function(trigger){
                $copyButton.tooltip('hide');
                return value;
            },
        });

        clipboard.on('success', function(e){
            tdTooltip("Copied!", "fa-check-circle");
        });

        clipboard.on('error', function(e){
            tdTooltip("Failed to copy.", "fa-times-circle");
        });

        $copyButton.appendTo($th);

    });

});
```

Not one bit of the above has any wiff of Symfony about it. It's all JavaScript and associated front end libraries.